# JUnit jar in Jenkins build not seen

Tags: ant, junit, jenkins

I have a build exported from svn that is failing on the 'TEST' target in my build.xml. It looks like Jenkins cannot see the junit.jar as I am getting the following error:

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestListener"
```

I installed the `xunit plug-in` and that didn't seem to work. I do have `JUnit4` installed on the unix host where the path is being set in the Ant `build.xml` file (this exact build works in a different build enviroment but not in Jenkins). Is there a place I need to set the JUnit path in Jenkins, such as under "Inject Enviroment Variables Into The Build"?

Comment: Are you using Ant 1.9.0, by chance? Take a look at [Bamboo Ant Task fails when running junit task](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16490171/1078068).

Comment: turns out using 1.9.0 was what was causing the issue, set the Ant build to 1.7.0 and it successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

turns out using 1.9.0 was what was causing the issue, set the Ant build to 1.7.0 and it successfully completed