# Bamboo Ant Task fails when running junit task

Tags: java, junit, ant, bamboo

In my current project I'm using junit tests. Runing my ant file on my local pc produces my Test Report as expected, but when bamboo tries to run my tests, it produces the following output.

Whats my mistake?

SimplerTest.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SimplerTest {


@Test
public void dummerTest()
{
    assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

Local Output:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\jussi\git\kingdom-builder-repository\build.xml

compile-test:
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jussi\git\kingdom-builder-repository\bin

junit:
    [junit] Running me.jussi.kingdombuilder.SimplerTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,062 sec

main:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Server Output:

```
compile-test:
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/KB-KBP1-JOB1/bin

junit:

BUILD FAILED
/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/KB-KBP1-JOB1/build.xml:108: Using loader AntClassLoader[/opt/apache-ant-1.9.0/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/opt/ant/lib/ant.jar:/opt/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/opt/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/KB-KBP1-JOB1/kingdom-builder/libs/junit-4.10.jar:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/KB-KBP1-JOB1/bin] 
on class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestListener
```

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="KingdomBuild" default="main" basedir=".">
<!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
<!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->

<property name="test.src.dir" location="kingdom-builder/test" />
<property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
<property name="test.report.dir" location="testreport" />

<!-- Define the classpath which includes the junit.jar and the classes after compiling-->
<path id="junit.class.path">
    <pathelement location="kingdom-builder/libs/junit-4.10.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
</path>

<!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
<target name="compile-test">
    <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
    </javac>
</target>


<!-- Run the JUnit Tests -->
<!-- Output is XML, could also be plain-->
<target name="junit" depends="compile-test">
    <junit printsummary="on" fork="true" haltonfailure="true">
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="junit">
    <description>Main target</description>
</target>
</project>
```

ant -v Output:

http://nopaste.info/1abdd27a8e.html

Comment: Is that all logging of the Bamboo server? `NoClassDefFoundError` is mostly caused when some other class is not found or fails to run its static code, so a real stacktrace of that Error or previous exceptions higher up in the log would help a lot. Can you somehow run the ant build with verbose logging?

Comment: I added the output of ant -v at the end of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the verbose Ant output.

It appears you are running Ant 1.9.0 on your Bamboo server. There is a known issue (bug [54835 - Classpath use seems to be broken in junit ant task?](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54835)) in the Ant bug tracker, which was started by the poster of a similar question on SO: "[Class not found with Ant, Ivy and JUnit - error in build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml)":

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/andrew/project/guice/hg/build.xml:33: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
...
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
...
```

That question didn't have a clear / short answer, but the bug report does:

> It looks like the class search is being delegated to the System's
>   classloader rather than being handled by the Ant Classloader (the
>   system Classloader has no knoweldge of JUnit since JUnit isn't on the
>   core Ant Classpath, but is added to the JUnit task by Ivy). Given some
>   JUnit classes must have already been loaded to have reached this
>   point, the Ant Classloader can see the JUnit jars loaded by Ivy, but
>   the Split Classloader seems to be delegating incorrectly when trying
>   to load classes used by the JUnit Runner.

In other words: Ant's JUnit task has bugs and won't work, and I think you are affected by this specific bug. The bug report goes on and lists these fixes / workarounds:

- Wait for Ant 1.9.1 (the bug report is marked as fixed and the release can be expected very soon)
- Copy your JUnit JAR into your `ANTLIB` directory and keep using Ant 1.9.0. This is not so good if you want to mix JUnit versions, but it should work if all you use is 4.10 or so.
- Use Ant 1.8.4

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I switched back to Ant 1.8.4.